# Why $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \cfrac{\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(u) du}{\Delta x}=\cfrac{f(x)\Delta x}{\Delta x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm reading Nahin's: *Inside Interesting Integrals*.

> [image]

I've been able to follow it until:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \cfrac{\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(u) du}{\Delta x}=\cfrac{f(x)\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$

I don't know what justifies the passage of the limit here. I've tried to write it as:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \left[ \cfrac{1}{\Delta x}\cdot \int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(u) du\right]=\left[\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \cfrac{1}{\Delta x}\right]\cdot \left[ \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(u) du \right]$$

But it seemed to create more non-sense than I previously had.

Comment: Isn't this just the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Stealing someone's great line: What Nahin wrote is so bad it's not even false.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous on $[x,x+\Delta x]$, then by the [MEAN VALUE THEOREM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration) there exists a number $\xi\in [x,x+\Delta x]$ such that

$$\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(x)\,dx=f(\xi)\Delta x$$

and as $f$ is continuous we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(x)\,dx=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}f(\xi)=f(x)}$$

Comment: MY +1. However we don't need the assumption of continuity in entire interval $[x, x + \Delta x]$. If $f$ is continuous at $c$ then we have for $\epsilon > 0$ an $h' > 0$ such that $$f(c) - \epsilon < f(t) < f(c) + \epsilon$$ for $c - h' < t < c + h'$. Integrating in the interval $[c, c + h]$ where $0 < h < h'$ and dividing by $h$ we get $$f(c) - \epsilon < \frac{1}{h}\int_{c}^{c + h}f(t)\,dt < f(c) + \epsilon$$ for all $0 < h < h'$ so that $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}\int_{c}^{c + h}f(t)\,dt = f(c)$$

Comment: @paramandsingh You would need to add that $f$ is integrable on $[c,c+h]$.

Comment: Yes! you are fully correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not actually rigorous what he says... but what he means is that, when $\Delta x $ approches $0$, then $f$ is approximately constant (assuming it is continuous). What you can do is, for instance:

Fix $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that: $f(x)-\epsilon<f(u)< f(x)+\epsilon$ for all $u$ in the $\delta$-neighbourhood of $x$. Therefore:

$ (f(x)-\epsilon) \Delta x \leq \int_x^{x+\Delta x} (f(x)- \epsilon) du \leq \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)du \leq \int_x^{x+\Delta x} (f(x)+ \epsilon) du =(f(x)+\epsilon) \Delta x $

which implies:

$$\displaystyle f(x)-\epsilon \leq \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)du}{\Delta x}\leq f(x)+\epsilon$$

Since this holds for every $\epsilon>0$, we have that

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)du}{\Delta x}=f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $f(x)$ is continuous. Then for every $\Delta x>0$ there exist $x_{\min},x_{\max}\in[x,x+\Delta x]$ such that 
$$
f_{\min}\leq f(t)\leq f(x_\max)
$$
for $t\in[x,x+\Delta x]$. Of course,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\Delta\to0}f(x_\min)&=f(x)&
\lim_{\Delta\to0}f(x_\max)&=f(x)
\end{align*}

Now, 
$$
f(x_\min)\leq
\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(t)\,dt\leq
f(x_\max)\tag{1}
$$
Taking $\Delta x\to 0$ in (1) gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider $$A= \cfrac{\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}f(u) du}{\Delta x} $$ and let $F(u)=\int f(u)du$. So the numerator is $F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)$ which is $\Delta x \,F'(x)=\Delta x \,f(x)$.